# ConnectionStrings error 26 - SQL / Visual Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, connection-string

I have added a database file (NORTHWND.MDF) to my application using Visual Studio 2010 built-in functionality. Database is in the App_Data folder. 
It is running fine in local-host. But when I publish it and upload it to server it gives this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

My connection string is that automatically generated by visual studio in my web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\NORTHWND.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

My host support SQL Express, but it dont work.. 
I read that once everything is upped on the host do not have to use "AttachDbFilename" .. but I have not figured out how to fix it .. Could someone tell me the correct connection string?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You Sholud  Use this connection String if you have your db attached to SQL management Studio

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

**Reference:**
**https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/**

Comment: Thank you very much! so it works perfectly, just that I had to remove "Integrated Security = SSPI;" or give me a login error.
thanks a lot